# In TypeScript why can't a parameterized function be assigned to a paramaterless function type?

Tags: typescript

I cannot assigned a parameterized function to a variable typed as a parameterless function:

```
var ak: () => void = (eventData: Human) => { };
```

I receive the compile time error:

*Error  TS2322  Type '(eventData: Human) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.*

However I can do the opposite:

```
var ak: (data: Human) => void = () => { };
```

Why is this?

Note I am using TS 1.4 with VS 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ak: (data: Human) => void = () => { };
```

What happens if you invoke a function that is expecting 1 argument with 0 arguments? The function will almost certainly fail.

```
var ak: (data: Human) => void = () => { };
```

What happens if you invoke a function that is expecting 0 arguments with 1 argument? The function will ignore the argument and life goes on as normal.

Why is it OK to ignore parameters? Consider this function (plucked from reality):

```
function forEach<T>(arr: T[], callback: (elem: T, index: number)) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        callback(arr[i], i);
    }
}
```

Let's use this function to print all the elements in an array:

```
function print(i: number) {
    console.log(i.toString());
}

forEach([1, 2, 3, 4], print);
```

We just passed two arguments to a function that only takes one! It would be *very* annoying if the compiler forced us to have to do something like this instead:

```
// Manually throw away the second parameter, ugh
forEach([1, 2, 3, 4], (x, y) => print(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Cavanaugh's answer gives the insight into why does it work like that.
I wanted to add that if you don't really care about the argument passed, you can make it optional:

```
var ak: () => void = (eventData?: Human) => { };
```

Note the question mark after the argument name.

This function will become assignable to `() => void`, but you should be ready to have `eventData` `undefined` in it.